# Apply a Frame Animation to a Toast View

Tags: android, animation, toast

Is it possible to play a frame animation on a Toast View?

Lines 3-5 in the code below are what usually works for me if I want to play a frame animation on a View.  Unfortunately when I try to apply that view to a toast object, it is not animating when the toast is shown.  **Does anyone know if it is possible to have a frame animation play on a toast object?  If so, how?**  Thanks

```
LayoutInflater inflaterSpin = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflaterSpin.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup)   findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

layout.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anim_toast);
AnimationDrawable toastAnim = (AnimationDrawable) layout.getBackground();
toastAnim.start();

myToast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());             
myToast.setView(layoutSpin);
myToast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, Did you try running the frame animation on a view in the activity?
According to this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818) the `toastAnim.start();` does not work. I have experienced this too. The solution to this was as given in the comments of the link above.. Goodluck. I beleive this should work in a toast too, since this worked for me in a view within an Activity.

NOTE: also i had placed the xml in the drawable folder, so it was **`R.drawable.frameanim`** and not `R.anim.frameanim`